# Solve[] giving wrong solutions to a system of two equations

Tags: differential-equations

I'm using solve to analytically find expressions for the equilibria of a differential equation. However when I put numbers into the results to check them, only one of the solutions is correct and the other two are incorrect.

```
(*Clear everything, just to be sure*)
Remove["Global`*"]

During evaluation of In[1]:= Remove::rmnsm: There are no symbols matching "Global`*".

(*Define the equations*)
dSdt = (S + I1)*(b - q*(S + I1)) - d *S - 
   BS*S/(En*(cS*cI*I1/(S + I1) + cS*cS*S/(S + I1))) - 
   En*cS*cI*Th*S*I1/(S + I1);
dI1dt = En*cS*cI*Th*S*I1 /(S + I1) - d *I1 - 
   BI*I1/(En*(cI*cI*I1/(S + I1) + cI*cS*S/(S + I1))) - v* I1;


(*Solve for the equations will be zero, in terms of S and I1*)
Equilibria = Solve[{dSdt == 0, dI1dt == 0}, {S, I1}];

(*Extract the equilibrial expressions*)
Seq1temp = Extract[Equilibria[[1, 1]], {2}];
Seq2temp = Extract[Equilibria[[2, 1]], {2}];
Seq3temp = Extract[Equilibria[[3, 1]], {2}];
I1eq1temp = Extract[Equilibria[[1, 2]], {2}];
I1eq2temp = Extract[Equilibria[[2, 2]], {2}];
I1eq3temp = Extract[Equilibria[[3, 2]], {2}];

(*Define some example parameter values*)
cSexample = 0.2;
cIexample = 0.2;
Enexample = 300;
bexample = 0.106;
qexample = 0.017;
dexample = 0.02071176;
Thexample = 0.000881;
vexample = 0.072;
BSexample = 6.47*10^-8;
BIexample = 6.47*10^-8;

(*Find equilibrium values. You can see that these are all \
real numbers.*)
Stest1 = Seq1temp /. {cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample, 
   En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
   Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}
Stest2 = Seq2temp /. {cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample, 
   En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
   Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}
Stest3 = Seq3temp /. {cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample, 
   En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
   Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}
Itest1 = I1eq1temp /. {cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample, 
   En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
   Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}
Itest2 = I1eq2temp /. {cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample, 
   En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
   Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}
Itest3 = I1eq3temp /. {cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample, 
   En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
   Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}

(*Outputs*)
5.01695

-89.

39.

0

-28.8889

3.11111

(*Test that the solutions make the equations be zero*)
(*This one works out fine, within some tiny numerical error*)
dSdt /. {S -> Stest1, I1 -> Itest1, cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample, 
  En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
  Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}
dI1dt /. {S -> Stest1, I1 -> Itest1, cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample,
   En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
  Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}

(*Outputs*)
-6.93889*10^-17

0.

(*This one does not work!*)
dSdt /. {S -> Stest2, I1 -> Itest2, cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample, 
  En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
  Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}
dI1dt /. {S -> Stest2, I1 -> Itest2, cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample,
   En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
  Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}

(*Outputs*)
-246.685

2.44777

(*Nor does this one!*)
dSdt /. {S -> Stest3, I1 -> Itest3, cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample, 
  En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
  Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}
dI1dt /. {S -> Stest3, I1 -> Itest3, cS -> cSexample, cI -> cIexample,
   En -> Enexample, b -> bexample, q -> qexample, d -> dexample, 
  Th -> Thexample, v -> vexample, BS -> BSexample, BI -> BIexample}

(*Outputs*)
-26.5213

-0.257976
```

I'm really hoping I made some small mistake somewhere but so far, I can't find it. I've used this general method before without a problem. The equilibrium expressions Seq2temp, Seq3temp, I1eq2temp, I1eq3temp are all certainly large outputs but I'm not sure why that would mess everything up while still returning a sensible expression.

Edit: For example, if I change the "/(En" part of both dSdt and dI1dt to "*(En" then everything works just fine and the solutions are indeed solutions.

Comment: Maybe the first thing that I notice, may not fix your problem, but certainly be sure that `Remove` is not the same as `ClearAll`. You should use the latter, and not the former as you have done.

Comment: I think you get numerical errors due to cancellation and 1/ small number. You may either rationalize your input. Or you can calculate numerically from the beginning.

Comment: I think you may have numerical imprecision problems, for example trying exact values: `cSexample = Rationalize[0.2, .001]
cIexample = Rationalize[0.2, .001];
Enexample = Rationalize[300, .001];
bexample = Rationalize[0.106, .001];
qexample = Rationalize[0.017, .001];
dexample = Rationalize[0.02071176, .001];
Thexample = Rationalize[0.000881, .001];
vexample = Rationalize[0.072, .001];
BSexample = Rationalize[6.47*10^-8, 10^-9]
BIexample = Rationalize[6.47*10^-8, 10^-9];`  I get division by zero.  You could try Simplify on your Equilibria to check if it is symbolically zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dSdt = (S + I1)*(b - q*(S + I1)) - d*S - 
   BS*S/(En*(cS*cI*I1/(S + I1) + cS*cS*S/(S + I1))) - 
   En*cS*cI*Th*S*I1/(S + I1);
dI1dt = En*cS*cI*Th*S*I1/(S + I1) - d*I1 - 
   BI*I1/(En*(cI*cI*I1/(S + I1) + cI*cS*S/(S + I1))) - v*I1;

param = {cS -> 0.2, cI -> 0.2, En -> 300, b -> 0.106, q -> 0.017, 
    d -> 0.02071176, Th -> 0.000881, v -> 0.072, BS -> 6.47*10^-8, 
    BI -> 6.47*10^-8} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

eqns = {dSdt == 0, dI1dt == 0} /. param // Simplify;

Equilibria = Solve[eqns, {S, I1}]

(* {{S -> 10234588153/2040000000, 
  I1 -> 0}, {S -> 44604592292893622544863/134120620800000000000, 
  I1 -> -(671810987790717391742671/2280050553600000000000)}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
eqns /. Equilibria

(* {{True, True}, {True, True}} *)
```

The approximate numeric values are

```
Equilibria /. r_Rational :> N[r]

(* {{S -> 5.01695, I1 -> 0}, {S -> 332.571, I1 -> -294.647}} *)

Show[
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[eqns],
  {S, -5, 350}, {I1, -300, 5},
  PlotPoints -> 90,
  MaxRecursion -> 3],
 Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{S, I1} /. Equilibria]}],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {S, I1})]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to test out other values

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{b, BI, BS, cI, cS, d, En, q, Th, v, eqns, pts},
  {b, BI, BS, cI, cS, d, En, q, Th, v} =
   Rationalize[{bv, BIv, BSv, cIv, cSv, dv, Env, qv, Thv, vv}, 0];
  dSdt = (S + I1)*(b - q*(S + I1)) - d*S - 
    BS*S/(En*(cS*cI*I1/(S + I1) + cS*cS*S/(S + I1))) - 
    En*cS*cI*Th*S*I1/(S + I1);
  dI1dt = 
   En*cS*cI*Th*S*I1/(S + I1) - d*I1 - 
    BI*I1/(En*(cI*cI*I1/(S + I1) + cI*cS*S/(S + I1))) - v*I1;
  eqns = {dSdt == 0, dI1dt == 0} // Simplify;
  Column[{
    (pts = SolveValues[eqns, {S, I1}, Method -> Reduce]) // N,
    And @@@ Simplify[eqns /. (Thread[{S, I1} -> #] & /@ pts)],
    Show[
     ContourPlot[Evaluate[eqns],
      {S, -5, 350}, {I1, -300, 5},
      PlotRange -> (MinMax /@ Transpose[pts]),
      PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
      PlotPoints -> 90,
      MaxRecursion -> 3],
     Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
       Point[pts]}],
     FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {S, I1}),
     ImageSize -> Medium]}]],
 {{bv, 0.106, "b"}, 0.002, 0.2, 0.002,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {{BIv, 6.47*^-8, "BI"}, 5.0*^-8, 8.0*^-8, 10^-10,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {{BSv, 6.47*^-8, "BS"}, 5.0*^-8, 8.0*^-8, 10^-10,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {{cIv, 0.2, "cI"}, 0, 1, 0.01,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {{cSv, 0.2, "cS"}, 0, 1, 0.01,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {{dv, 0.02071176, "d"}, 0.01, 0.03, 10^-4,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {{Env, 300, "En"}, 10, 1000, 5,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {{qv, 0.017, "q"}, 0.001, 0.25, 0.001,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {{Thv, 0.000881, "Th"}, 0.0001, 0.001, 10^-5,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {{vv, 0.072, "v"}, 0.005, 0.15, 10^-3,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {bv, BIv, BSv, cIv, cSv, dv, Env, qv, Thv, vv}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you! I am able to reproduce this code just fine and I think I mostly understand. So this was an issue of numerical precision? Also, I would like to have an expression for the solution into which I can plug many different parameter values. Your example seems to find the solution for a particular set of parameter values?

Comment: Thanks Bob! That's really nice to be able to play with other values that way and I'm really glad I've learned the "Manipulate" function now.